# How to remove text channels with duplicate names with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with discord.js v12.

When I try to make a command for adding or removing a text channel, it works for only 1 channel, but when there are channels with the same name, you should specify how many you want to be removed, removing single channel works, but removing multiple if they exist returns `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel`

My remove command's code:

```
execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send('removing').then(async sent => {
    const channelName = args[0];
    const amount = args[1] ? args[1] : 1;
    console.log(amount, channelName);
    for (let index = 0; index < amount; index++) {
      const exist = await message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === channelName);
      if (exist) exist.delete();
    }
    sent.delete();
  });
}
```

`If` statements couldn't resolve it

appreciate any bit of help

I tried fetching the guilds.channels with `await message.guild.channels.fetch();` before awaiting exist. but it says:

> TypeError: message.guild.channels.fetch is not a function

I couldn't figure out any other solutions

Comment: The fetch function doesn't exist in v12 ([Guide](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildChannelManager)). What you could do would be not using the channel name but the ID, so when running the command the input is 'the channel mention' (<#123456789123456789>). This way, the channel is always one.

Comment: Discord.js v12 is deprecated, and will be losing support soon. Update to v13 or v14

Comment: Thank y'll, I'll upgrade it
I use 14 for my projects,
this is a project from a while ago so it's still using v12, I'll update as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is that discord.js v12 is deprecated so this is the code for v14

```js
async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "Removing...", ephemeral: true });
        const amount = interaction.options.getInteger('amount') ?? 500;
        const community = ['rules', 'moderator-only'];
        const currentChId = interaction.channel.id;
        const name = interaction.options.getString('name') ?? undefined;
        if (isNaN(amount) | (Number(amount) < 0)) {
            await interaction.editReply({ content: "You should provide a valid integer bigger than zero", ephemeral: true });
            return;
        }
        for (let index = 0; index <= amount; index++) {
            let cr;
            if (name != undefined) {
                cr = await interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.name === name).first();
            }
            else {
                cr = await interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => !community.includes(ch.name) && !(currentChId == ch)).first();
            }
            if (!cr) {
                break;
            }
            if (cr.deletable) {
                await cr.delete();
            }
            else {
                await interaction.followUp({ content: `Couldn't delete ${cr.name}`, ephemeral: true });
            }
        }
        await interaction.editReply({ content: "Done", ephemeral: true });

    }
```

or just the line: for deleting:
await interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.name === name).first()
the .first() method returns the first one so if there is a duplicate it just gonna returns the first one